# How can I easily add programming syntax to the iPhone keyboard?

Tags: iphone, ios, keyboard, dictionary

I want to dump a list of syntax from python, Cpp, bash, etc into my iPhones dictionary so it doesn’t auto correct away. I don’t want to do this manually for each word. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a contact and add the syntax words into the notes or workplace (copied from wikipedia or elsewhere).

Source: https://gigaom.com/2011/10/11/ios-quick-tip-mastering-the-auto-correct-dictionary/